# To colored the particular country using amcharts using country name

Tags: javascript, maps, amcharts

I have map amchart in which i want to colored the particular country Like this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dpacq.png)

I have tried this code but this is creating circle. How it is achieved?

```
 AmCharts.makeChart( "mapdiv",
                     {
                      "type": "map",  
                      "dataProvider": {
                        "map": "worldLow",
                        "images": [ {
                          "latitude": <?php echo $lat;?>,
                          "longitude": <?php echo $long;?>,
                          "type": "circle",
                          "width": 25,
                          "height":  25,
                          "color": "#926681",
                          "title": "<?php echo $selectedctry;?>",
                        } ]
                      },
                      "areasSettings": {
                        "autoZoom": true,
                      },

                      "areasSettings": {
                      "unlistedAreasColor": "#000", 
                        "alpha": 0.5
                      },
                      "disableDoubleClickZoom": true,
                        "zoomControl": {
                          "zoomControlEnabled": true
                          //"zoomOnDoubleClick": false
                       }
                     }
 );
```

Any suggestion how it can be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

An image in the `images` array just places an image onto the map at the desired latitude and longitude coordinates. If you want to color a country, you have to specify it in the `areas` array in the `dataProvider` by referencing the country's id, which is its ISO-3166 two character country code (for example, Argentina is AR, Brazil is BR, etc):

```
  "dataProvider": {
    "map": "worldLow",
    "areas": [{
      "id": "AR",
      "color": "#ccdd00"
    },{
      "id": "BR",
      "color": "#aaff00"
    },
    // repeat for each country
   ]
  }
```

Demo:

```js
var map = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "map",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": {
    "map": "worldLow",
    "areas": [{
      "id": "AR",
      "color": "#ccdd00"
    },{
      "id": "BR",
      "color": "#aaff00"
    },
    // repeat for each country
   ]
  },
  "areasSettings": {
    "autoZoom": true,
    "selectedColor": "#CC0000"
  }
});
```

```css
 #chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/ammap.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/maps/js/worldLow.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

You can find all the properties you can set for an area in the areas array [here](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/MapArea).